# Can I take the biochemistry GRE test if I am a biology graduate?

Tags: gre

I currently hold a bachelor of science in botany but plan to do a master's in genetics. I was wondering if I can take the GRE subject test for biochemistry, molecular biology, and genetics, or am I eligible for biology graduate record test  only?

Comment: This is **not** an undergraduate question, since it's asking about GRE subject tests! This is an admissions question.

Answer (score 7):

There are no requirements on who can take a GRE subject test. So long as you pay the test fee, they're happy to take your money, even if you've never taken a course in the subject in your life. You're a French major who wants to take the mathematics GRE? *Bien sur !*